# How to get the compressed size (ZipArchive ) of a FileStream block?

Tags: c#, stream, zip, zlib, appx

I'm writing a little C# appx package editor (appx is basically a zip file containing a bunch of XML metadata files).

In order to make a valid appx file, I need to create a block map file (XML) that contains for each file two attributes : hash and size as explained here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/blockmapschema/element-block)

Hash represent a 64kb uncompressed chunk of a file. Size represent the size of that chunk after being compressed (deflate algorithm). Here is what I wrote so far as proof of concept :

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;

namespace StreamTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var srcFile = File.OpenRead(@"C:\Test\sample.txt"))
            {
                ZipAndHash(srcFile);
            }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ZipAndHash(Stream inStream)
    {
        const int blockSize = 65536; //64KB
        var uncompressedBuffer = new byte[blockSize];
        int bytesRead;
        int totalBytesRead = 0;

        //Create a ZIP file
        using (FileStream zipStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Test\test.zip", FileMode.Create))
        {
            using (ZipArchive zipArchive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
            {
                using (BinaryWriter zipWriter = new BinaryWriter(zipArchive.CreateEntry("test.txt").Open()))
                {
                    //Read stream with a 64kb buffer
                    while ((bytesRead = inStream.Read(uncompressedBuffer, 0, uncompressedBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        totalBytesRead = totalBytesRead + bytesRead;

                        //Compress current block to the Zip entry 
                        if (uncompressedBuffer.Length == bytesRead)
                        {
                            //Hash each 64kb block before compression
                            hashBlock(uncompressedBuffer);

                            //Compress
                            zipWriter.Write(uncompressedBuffer);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //Hash remaining bytes and compress
                            hashBlock(uncompressedBuffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray());
                            zipWriter.Write(uncompressedBuffer.Take(bytesRead).ToArray());
                        }
                    }

                    //How to obtain the size of the compressed block after invoking zipWriter.Write() ?

                    Console.WriteLine($"total bytes : {totalBytesRead}");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    private static void hashBlock(byte[] uncompressedBuffer)
    {
        // hash the block
    }
  }
}
```

I can easily get the hash attribute by using a 64kb buffer while reading a stream, my question is :

How do I obtain the compressed size of each 64kb block after using zipWrite.Write(), is it even possible with System.IO.Compression or should I use something else ?

Comment: Can you get it from the ZipArchive object? Something like zipArchive.GetEntry("test.txt").CompressedLength

Comment: Sadly not : NotSupportedException The zip archive does not support reading , probably because the entry is not totally written still.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem still actual, for creating container you can use 2 approach:

1. **Managed OPC Packaging APIs**, which provide support for applications that produce or consume Open Packaging Conventions compliant files, called packages, and develop all specific things by yourself (general description is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371623(v=vs.85).aspx)

For getting blocks compression size on-the-fly you can use DeflateStream and MemoryStream like below:

```
      private static long getCompressSize(byte[] input)
    {

        long length = 0;

        using (MemoryStream compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            compressedStream.Position = 0;

            using (DeflateStream compressionStream = new DeflateStream(compressedStream, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true))
            {
                compressionStream.Write(input, 0, input.Length);

            }


            length = compressedStream.Length;

        }
        Logger.WriteLine("input length:" + input.Length + " compressed stream: " + length);
        return length;
    }
```

2. **C++ API for Appx containers** (but in this case Project should be rewritten using C++ or additional library should be written and imported to C# project).
   The main advantage is that it already has methods for create all needed package parts. General description is here (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh446766(v=vs.85).aspx)

**Solution for getting block size and Hash:**

The IAppxBlockMapBlock interface provides a read-only object that represents an individual block within a file contained in the block map file (AppxBlockMap.xml) for the App package. The IAppxBlockMapFile::GetBlocks method is used to return an enumerator for traversing and retrieving the individual blocks of a file listed in the package block map.

The IAppxBlockMapBlock interface inherits from the IUnknown interface and has these methods:

**GetCompressedSize - Retrieves compressed size of the block.**

**GetHash - Retrieves the hash value of the block.**

Comment: @Eugene I just edited your answer to avoid unwanted interpretation. Also a tip is to add the relevent pieces from the links you provides so your answer will still be helpfull in case the links change/break.

Comment: @André thanks.
 Added more detailed answer for better perception. But i still think that links are needed, because behind them people can find general API's description.